# TypeError: 'GroupedData' object is not iterable in pyspark dataframe

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have a Spark dataframe `sdf` with GPS points that looks like this:

```
d = {'user': ['A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'B', 'B', 'B', 'C', 'C', 'C', 'C', 'C', 'A', 'A'], 
     'lat': [37.75243634842733, 37.75344580658182, 37.75405656449232, 37.753649393112181,37.75409897804892, 37.753937806404586, 37.72767062183685, 37.72710631810977, 37.72605407110467, 37.71141865080228, 37.712199505873926, 37.713285899241896, 37.71428740401767, 37.712810604103346, 37.75405656449232, 37.753649393112181], 
     'lon': [-122.41924881935118, -122.42006421089171, -122.419216632843, -122.41784334182738, -122.4169099330902, -122.41549372673035, -122.3878937959671, -122.3884356021881, -122.38841414451599, -122.44688630104064, -122.44474053382874, -122.44361400604248, -122.44260549545288, -122.44156479835509, -122.4169099330902, -122.41549372673035],
     'date': ['2018-02-03', '2018-02-03', '2018-02-03', '2018-02-03', '2018-02-03', '2018-02-03', '2018-02-03', '2018-02-03', '2018-02-03', '2018-02-03', '2018-02-03', '2018-02-03', '2018-02-03', '2018-02-03', '2018-02-04', '2018-02-04'],
 'radius': [10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10]}
pdf = pd.DataFrame(data=d)
sdf = spark.createDataFrame(pdf)

+----+------------------+-------------------+----------+------+
|user|               lat|                lon|      date|radius|
+----+------------------+-------------------+----------+------+
|   A| 37.75243634842733|-122.41924881935118|2018-02-03|    10|
|   A| 37.75344580658182|-122.42006421089171|2018-02-03|    10|
|   A| 37.75405656449232|  -122.419216632843|2018-02-03|    10|
|   A|37.753649393112184|-122.41784334182738|2018-02-03|    10|
|   A| 37.75409897804892| -122.4169099330902|2018-02-03|    10|
|   A|37.753937806404586|-122.41549372673035|2018-02-03|    10|
|   B| 37.72767062183685| -122.3878937959671|2018-02-03|    10|
|   B| 37.72710631810977| -122.3884356021881|2018-02-03|    10|
|   B| 37.72605407110467|-122.38841414451599|2018-02-03|    10|
|   C| 37.71141865080228|-122.44688630104064|2018-02-03|    10|
|   C|37.712199505873926|-122.44474053382874|2018-02-03|    10|
|   C|37.713285899241896|-122.44361400604248|2018-02-03|    10|
|   C| 37.71428740401767|-122.44260549545288|2018-02-03|    10|
|   C|37.712810604103346|-122.44156479835509|2018-02-03|    10|
|   A| 37.75405656449232| -122.4169099330902|2018-02-04|    10|
|   A|37.753649393112184|-122.41549372673035|2018-02-04|    10|
+----+------------------+-------------------+----------+------+
```

Since the spark dataframe contains different GPS trajectories generated by different users on different days, I want to write a function that loops through this df and feeds the corresponding set of coordinates to the (OSRM) request per `date` and per `user` group and not all at once.

```
from typing import Dict, Any, List, Tuple
import pyspark.sql.functions as F
import requests

# Format coordinates into a concatenated string formatted for the OSRM server
def format_coords(df):
    coords = df.agg(F.concat_ws(';', F.collect_list(F.format_string('%f,%f', 'lon', 'lat')))).head()[0]
    return(coords)

# Format dictionary of additional options to the OSRM request into a concatenated string format.
def format_options(options: Dict[str, str]) -> str:
    options = "&".join([f"{k}={v}" for k, v in options.items()])
    return options

# Format radiuses into a concatenated string formatted for the OSRM server
def format_radiuses(df):
    radiuses = "&radiuses=" + df.agg(F.concat_ws(';', F.collect_list(F.format_string('%d', 'radius')))).head()[0]
    return(radiuses)
 
# Make request   
def make_request(coords, radiuses, options):
    coords = format_coords(coords)
    radiuses = format_radiuses(radiuses)
    options = format_options(options) if options else ""
    url = f"http://router.project-osrm.org/match/v1/car/{coords}?{options}{radiuses}"
    r = requests.get(url)
    return r.json()
```

Unfortunately, running the code blow returns a `TypeError: 'GroupedData' object is not iterable`. What am I missing:

```
output = {}
for trip, g in sdf.groupBy('date', 'user'):
    output[trip] = make_request(coords = sdf[['lat', 'lon']],
                                radiuses = sdf[['radius']],
                                options = {'overview':'full',
                                           'geometries': 'polyline6',
                                           'annotations': 'nodes'})
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try aggregating the string after group by:

```
import pyspark.sql.functions as F
import requests

def format_options(options):
    options = "&".join([f"{k}={v}" for k, v in options.items()])
    return options

def make_request(coords, radiuses, options):
    options = format_options(options) if options else ""
    url = f"http://router.project-osrm.org/match/v1/car/{coords}?{options}&radiuses={radiuses}"
    r = requests.get(url)
    print(url)
    return r.json()

coords = sdf.groupBy('date', 'user').agg(
    F.concat_ws(';', 
        F.collect_list(F.format_string('%f,%f', 'lon', 'lat'))
    ).alias('coords'),
    F.concat_ws(';', 
        F.collect_list(F.format_string('%d', 'radius'))
    ).alias('radius')
).collect()

options = {'overview':'full', 'geometries': 'polyline6', 'annotations': 'nodes'}
output = {(c[0], c[1]): make_request(c[2], c[3], options) for c in coords}

"""
{('2018-02-03', 'A'): {'code': 'Ok',
                       'matchings': [{'confidence': 0.374625,
                                      'distance': 325.2,
                                      'duration': 50.6,
                                      'geometry': 'y{h_gAh~znhF}@k[OmFMoFcAea@IeD[uMAYKsDMsDAe@}@u_@g@aTMwFMwFwAqq@',
                                      'legs': [{'annotation': {'nodes': [1974590926,
                                                                         4763953263,
                                                                         65359046,
                                                                         4763953265,
                                                                         5443374298,
                                                                         2007343352]},
                                                'distance': 116.7,
                                                'duration': 18.8,
                                                'steps': [],
                                                'summary': '',
                                                'weight': 18.8},
                                               {'annotation': {'nodes': [5443374298,
                                                                         2007343352,
                                                                         4763953266,
                                                                         65359043,
                                                                         4763953269,
                                                                         2007343354,
                                                                         4763953270]},
                                                'distance': 85.6,
                                                'duration': 12.2,
                                                'steps': [],
                                                'summary': '',
                                                'weight': 12.2},
                                               {'annotation': {'nodes': [2007343354,
                                                                         4763953270,
                                                                         65334199,
                                                                         4763953274,
                                                                         2007343347]},
                                                'distance': 122.9,
                                                'duration': 19.6,
                                                'steps': [],
                                                'summary': '',
                                                'weight': 19.6}],
                                      'weight': 50.6,
                                      'weight_name': 'routability'}],
                       'tracepoints': [None,
                                       None,
                                       {'alternatives_count': 0,
                                        'distance': 28.078003,
                                        'hint': '20nBh2NdHwA2AAAAOgAAAAwAAAAPAAAAiVMWQq2VIEIAuABB7FgoQTYAAAA6AAAADAAAAA8AAABDRAAACwi0-M0TQALvB7T4yRRAAgEAXwUADb92',
                                        'location': [-122.419189, 37.753805],
                                        'matchings_index': 0,
                                        'name': '23rd Street',
                                        'waypoint_index': 0},
                                       {'alternatives_count': 0,
                                        'distance': 26.825184,
                                        'hint': 'Ew3BBzFbH4AdAAAACwAAAA0AAAAAAAAAIxmmQTSs6kCiuRFBAAAAAB0AAAALAAAADQAAAAAAAABDRAAANg20-CIUQAJNDbT4MRNAAgIAnxAADb92',
                                        'location': [-122.417866, 37.75389],
                                        'matchings_index': 0,
                                        'name': '23rd Street',
                                        'waypoint_index': 1},
                                       {'alternatives_count': 0,
                                        'distance': 16.583412,
                                        'hint': 'DQ3BBxQNwYcqAAAAQwAAABAAAAANAAAA0i_uQb3SOEKKPC9BG1EaQSoAAABDAAAAEAAAAA0AAABDRAAAABG0-F4UQALyELT48xRAAgEAnxAADb92',
                                        'location': [-122.416896, 37.75395],
                                        'matchings_index': 0,
                                        'name': '23rd Street',
                                        'waypoint_index': 2},
                                       {'alternatives_count': 7,
                                        'distance': 10.013916,
                                        'hint': 'Dg3Bh1WcyQBmAAAACAAAABAAAAANAAAAQOKOQg89nkCKPC9BEMcOQWYAAAAIAAAAEAAAAA0AAABDRAAAcha0-KwUQAJ6FrT4UhRAAgEAbwUADb92',
                                        'location': [-122.415502, 37.754028],
                                        'matchings_index': 0,
                                        'name': '23rd Street',
                                        'waypoint_index': 3}]},
 ('2018-02-03', 'B'): {'code': 'Ok',
                       'matchings': [{'confidence': 1e-06,
                                      'distance': 270.4,
                                      'duration': 50,
                                      'geometry': 'euu}fAd_~lhFoAlCMTuAvCvC|Bh@`@hXbUnAdADBhDzCzClCXVzZnW\\X~CnC~@qBLWnWej@',
                                      'legs': [{'annotation': {'nodes': [5443147626,
                                                                         6360865540,
                                                                         6360865536,
                                                                         65307580,
                                                                         6360865535,
                                                                         6360865539,
                                                                         6360865531]},
                                                'distance': 84.8,
                                                'duration': 17.8,
                                                'steps': [],
                                                'summary': '',
                                                'weight': 17.8},
                                               {'annotation': {'nodes': [6360865539,
                                                                         6360865531,
                                                                         6360865525,
                                                                         65343521,
                                                                         6360865527,
                                                                         6360865529,
                                                                         6360865523,
                                                                         6360865520,
                                                                         65321110,
                                                                         6360865519,
                                                                         6360865522,
                                                                         6376329343]},
                                                'distance': 185.6,
                                                'duration': 32.2,
                                                'steps': [],
                                                'summary': '',
                                                'weight': 32.2}],
                                      'weight': 50,
                                      'weight_name': 'routability'}],
                       'tracepoints': [{'alternatives_count': 0,
                                        'distance': 11.53267,
                                        'hint': 'ZpfJAOSXyYALAAAArQAAAA4AAAAsAAAAnpH1QDVG8EJWgBdBa2v0QQsAAACtAAAADgAAACwAAABDRAAA_YG0-GOtPwJKgrT4t60_AgIA3wcADb92',
                                        'location': [-122.387971, 37.727587],
                                        'matchings_index': 0,
                                        'name': 'Underwood Avenue',
                                        'waypoint_index': 0},
                                       {'alternatives_count': 0,
                                        'distance': 13.565054,
                                        'hint': 'ZZfJgALywAdPAAAACAAAABMAAAASAAAA7ONaQo4CrUDv7U1BJdFAQU8AAAAIAAAAEwAAABIAAABDRAAArX-0-MerPwIsgLT4gqs_AgIAbw0ADb92',
                                        'location': [-122.388563, 37.727175],
                                        'matchings_index': 0,
                                        'name': 'Jennings Street',
                                        'waypoint_index': 1},
                                       {'alternatives_count': 1,
                                        'distance': 9.601917,
                                        'hint': 'WZfJAP7xwIecAAAAbAAAABEAAAALAAAAdujYQqu4lUJXHD1B9-ruQJwAAABsAAAAEQAAAAsAAABDRAAAAoC0-CCnPwJCgLT4Zqc_AgIAHxMADb92',
                                        'location': [-122.388478, 37.725984],
                                        'matchings_index': 0,
                                        'name': 'Wallace Avenue',
                                        'waypoint_index': 2}]},
 ('2018-02-03', 'C'): {'code': 'Ok',
                       'matchings': [{'confidence': 7.3e-05,
                                      'distance': 420.1,
                                      'duration': 64.1,
                                      'geometry': 'kuy|fAbyjphFcBxEmE`FqJkKiBqBuP}Qgc@ie@eAiAcB}ArA_Eb@mAjKkDnBo@fe@mOrw@kW',
                                      'legs': [{'annotation': {'nodes': [5440513673,
                                                                         5440513674,
                                                                         5440513675,
                                                                         65363070,
                                                                         1229920760,
                                                                         65307726,
                                                                         6906452420,
                                                                         1229920717,
                                                                         65361047,
                                                                         1229920749,
                                                                         554163599,
                                                                         3978809925]},
                                                'distance': 235.2,
                                                'duration': 37.5,
                                                'steps': [],
                                                'summary': '',
                                                'weight': 40.1},
                                               {'annotation': {'nodes': [554163599,
                                                                         3978809925,
                                                                         65345518,
                                                                         8256268328]},
                                                'distance': 184.9,
                                                'duration': 26.6,
                                                'steps': [],
                                                'summary': '',
                                                'weight': 26.6}],
                                      'weight': 66.7,
                                      'weight_name': 'routability'}],
                       'tracepoints': [None,
                                       None,
                                       {'alternatives_count': 0,
                                        'distance': 6.968076,
                                        'hint': 'KLvAhyu7wAcAAAAANQAAAAAAAAAkAAAAAAAAAOCMMUEAAAAA_Z1yQQAAAAAbAAAAAAAAACQAAABDRAAAXqiz-GZ1PwKiqLP4hnU_AgAAzxIADb92',
                                        'location': [-122.443682, 37.713254],
                                        'matchings_index': 0,
                                        'name': '',
                                        'waypoint_index': 0},
                                       {'alternatives_count': 0,
                                        'distance': 16.488956,
                                        'hint': '-rrAB_aPyYAJAAAAIgAAAGgAAAAUAAAA2RnSQL_5uUEPjI9CBTlaQQkAAAAiAAAAaAAAABQAAABDRAAARK2z-J95PwKTrLP4b3k_AgEAXxUADb92',
                                        'location': [-122.442428, 37.714335],
                                        'matchings_index': 0,
                                        'name': 'Allison Street',
                                        'waypoint_index': 1},
                                       {'alternatives_count': 1,
                                        'distance': 17.311636,
                                        'hint': '_brAhwC7wAeZAAAANwAAAAAAAAAKAAAAH4vUQgKXFkIAAAAAXtbYQJkAAAA3AAAAAAAAAAoAAABDRAAA6a-z-HlzPwKjsLP4q3M_AgAAHwoADb92',
                                        'location': [-122.441751, 37.712761],
                                        'matchings_index': 0,
                                        'name': 'Allison Street',
                                        'waypoint_index': 2}]},
 ('2018-02-04', 'A'): {'code': 'Ok',
                       'matchings': [{'confidence': 0,
                                      'distance': 205.5,
                                      'duration': 46.4,
                                      'geometry': '{di_gAfovnhFg@iTMwFbCMlXmApH[k@iJoB{l@uFH',
                                      'legs': [{'annotation': {'nodes': [2007343354,
                                                                         4763953270,
                                                                         65334199,
                                                                         4763953267,
                                                                         5443374265,
                                                                         5443374261,
                                                                         5443374264,
                                                                         5443374263,
                                                                         5544172171]},
                                                'distance': 205.5,
                                                'duration': 46.4,
                                                'steps': [],
                                                'summary': '',
                                                'weight': 46.4}],
                                      'weight': 46.4,
                                      'weight_name': 'routability'}],
                       'tracepoints': [{'alternatives_count': 0,
                                        'distance': 11.908542,
                                        'hint': 'DQ3BBxQNwYcrAAAAQgAAABAAAAANAAAAkv_wQeJqN0KKPC9BG1EaQSsAAABCAAAAEAAAAA0AAABDRAAA_BC0-F4UQALyELT4yRRAAgEAnxAADb92',
                                        'location': [-122.4169, 37.75395],
                                        'matchings_index': 0,
                                        'name': '23rd Street',
                                        'waypoint_index': 0},
                                       {'alternatives_count': 6,
                                        'distance': 11.065027,
                                        'hint': 'kQ3Bh____38hAAAAIQAAAMMAAAAAAAAApopaQQAAAADsMaJCAAAAACEAAAAhAAAAwwAAAAAAAABDRAAAlxa0-NASQAJ6FrT4MRNAAgIAbxYADb92',
                                        'location': [-122.415465, 37.753552],
                                        'matchings_index': 0,
                                        'name': '',
                                        'waypoint_index': 1}]}}
"""
```

Comment: Thanks! Although it works, the output is a spark dataframe, while I would like to have it returned as a JSON object. I can achieve this with: `output = {}
for trip, g in sdf.groupBy('user').count().collect():
    output[trip] = make_request(coords = sdf[['latitude', 'longitude']])`, but then it is only grouped per user, and not also per date. Do you have any ideas?

Comment: Yes and it works. But it has become a bit more unclear how I can incorporate this in the rest of my code. I make the request also with a `options` and `radius` parameter, so I was hoping I could easily adapt your answer into my code, but it has become quite different. I have updated my question so you can see what I'm trying to achieve. There's no option to make a minor adjustion to my code to make it work?

Comment: @sampeterson see edited answer? Your code has to be refactored because you can't work on `df.groupBy` - this is not pandas, and you need to do an aggregation after group by.

Comment: You're a legend. Thanks a lot for your time :)

Comment: I did notice that especially the `coords = sdf.groupBy('date', 'user').agg(...` takes quite long for bigger datasets. Is there a way to speed things up?

Comment: bigger datasets will take longer... take your time and be patient :)